# How to make a slider using only as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I am trying to make a slider in flash builder not using the Flash Professional API, but i dont know how to do it. Is there a class I could call like var sider:Slider?

Please someone help.

Comment: You can whip out a Slider class by yourself, [find a tutorial](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=as3+slider+class+tutorial&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB524GB524&aq=f&oq=as3+slider+class+tutorial&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l2.6956&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or try something like [MinimalComponents](http://www.minimalcomps.com/) if you don't want to use `fl.controls.*`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a slider to your library first. Go to window, then components and drag a slider in to your library.
You can create a new slider in code by creating a slider-object.

```
import fl.controls.Slider;
var sliderObj:Slider = new Slider();
addChild(sliderObj);
```

Comment: Thank Matt, but I get this error: Multiple markers at this line:
-Definition fl.controls.Slider could not be 
 found.
-The import fl.controls.Slider is not used locally
-2 added lines

Comment: Is the slider in your library AS-linked to fl.controls.Slider?

Comment: @Scope sounds like the Slider component isn't in your document's library like Matt advised. Simply drag it there from the Components Panel (Window > Components)

Comment: Note that you won't have a library for your project if you're _not using Flash Professional_, as stated by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to this url :

http://apdevblog.com/update-using-flvideo-package-w-eclipse-and-fdt3/

Download the fl_package.swc on that page and add that .swc to your flash builder project.

You can add the swc via the Flash Builder menu system like this :

Project/Properties/Actionscript Build Path -- > click the Add SWC button and browse to the location of the fl_package.swc to add it.

Now you can use the Slider class by first adding this line to your imports wherever you want to us it :

```
import fl.controls.Slider
```

and then you can create an instance in your code and add it to the stage like this :

```
var mySlider:Slider = new Slider();
addChild(mySlider);
```

Comment: hello @prototypical, thanks for the answer, I have a problem I did what you said, but nothing is showing up in the window
here is my code just incase:

`package
{
 import fl.controls.Slider;
 
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 
 public class Slider extends Sprite
 {
  
  private var mySlider:Slider = new Slider();
  
  public function Slider()
  {
   mySlider.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
   mySlider.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
   addChild(mySlider);
  }
 }
}`

Comment: I think you are confused. You are not creating a Slider class, you are  just importing that class and creating an instance of it. Call your class Main or whatever.

Comment: O no I understand I just call the project Slider, so I could know thats what I'm doing in that project.@prototypical